# Does China still import defense tech and products from Israel?

Tags: china, israel, weapons

As we know, China was a prominent customer of Israeli defense products [during the 1990s](http://www.newsweek.com/china-israel-military-technology-beijing-jerusalem-saul-eisenberg-weapons-607117).

Does China still import defense tech or finished products from Israel?

What is the latest trend?

Comment: would u accept any date in the 2010's or must it be 2017

Comment: @SleepingGod, i want to know the latest trend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since early 2000s, generally no.

As a policy, Israel coordinates the export of security technology with the USA, which sees exports to China unfavorably.

This is the situation since the 2000 cancellation, by American requirement, of the [Falcon deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EL/W-2090#Sale_to_China), which greatly angered the Chinese government.

Since then, security export from Israel to China is generally prohibited ([Hebrew source](http://www.themarker.com/news/macro/1.2216440)).

However, detailed information about security exports is hard to find. It's possible that some deals are done after all, but probably not at large scale.